# Place a title on a plot in shiny using html/css

Tags: r, shiny

I have this example app with a wordcloud plot where the wordcloud has no title option. So I'm trying to place a title ontop of it. I have having some trouble. Here is the example app:

```
df <- structure(list(key = c("Hello", "Okay", "Apple", "Orange", "Cheerios", 
"Today", "Tomorrow", "Water", "Steve", "Basket"), value = c(52L, 
51L, 25L, 21L, 20L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 11L, 9L)), row.names = c(57L, 
53L, 20L, 36L, 18L, 3L, 16L, 50L, 13L, 15L), class = "data.frame")

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(width = 6,
        HTML("<div>"),
        HTML("<h2 style='color:black; z-index: 9'>User Ranking</h2>"),
        wordcloud2Output("plot1", height = '500px')
        HTML("</div>")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$plot1 <- renderWordcloud2({
      require('wordcloud2')
      data.frame(word = df$key, count = df$value) %>% wordcloud2(., size=.7, color='random-dark')

  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

If I put the title first, the plot just moves down. I want the plot to be in the same spot with the title just ontop of it in the top left. I tried to put it in a div and change the z-index of the  tag, but that didn't help.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put `style='position:absolute;'` in the `<h*>`-tag to achieve this. I am not sure if it is a good idea, as it might lead to overplotting of wordcloud content and the title, but if you are certain that that area will never be used for wordcloud content I guess you can do it that way.

```
library(shiny)
library(wordcloud2)
library(tidyverse)

df <- structure(list(key = c("Hello", "Okay", "Apple", "Orange", "Cheerios", 
                         "Today", "Tomorrow", "Water", "Steve", "Basket"), 
                 value = c(52L, 51L, 25L, 21L, 20L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 11L, 9L)), 
            row.names = c(57L, 53L, 20L, 36L, 18L, 3L, 16L, 50L, 13L, 15L),
            class = "data.frame")

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(width = 6,
           HTML("<div>"),
           HTML("<h2 style='color:black; z-index: 9'>User Ranking</h2>"),
           HTML("<h2 style='position:absolute;'>TITLE</h2>"),
           wordcloud2Output("plot1", height = '500px'),
           HTML("</div>")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$plot1 <- renderWordcloud2({
    require('wordcloud2')
    data.frame(word = df$key, count = df$value) %>% wordcloud2(., size=.7, color='random-dark')
    
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```